# Where does dd start when copying a partition?

Tags: partition, backup, hard-disk

I'm copying an entire HDD using the `dd` tool, and I'm considering stopping part of the backup  due to space limitations.

Does the `dd` tool begin at the front of a partition when copying? The first ~90 GB are the relevant parts as they contain boot information, everything else can be ignored if necessary.

I could not find this information in the manpages.

Comment: Yes it does. At least when I tried.  However I am not sure that it may be taken for granted on all systems and don't know how to limit its backup.
Notion of the start of partition breaks particularly easy on more exotic RAIDs and LVMs or similar.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I read the dd manual and did not find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:** with dd you can destroy data very easily, make sure you have backups and are familiar with `dd` before using it

`dd` starts copying from the first byte of the disk you specify, including the master boot record, mbr. For example http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/mbr.bak bs=512 count=1
```

This will copy the first 512 bytes of your hdd (in this case sda). This data is before the first partition.

You can change `bs=512 count=1` to something like `count=90G` 
http://maarten.lippmann.us/?page_id=116

If you only want to copy boot info however this may be too much data, in general boot information would not be that big.